# Passing an arbitrary lambda expression to a function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I have a pretty exotic problem, since I am trying to create some sort of a compiler...
I want to pass a lambda expression to a templated function like this:

```
    template<class T>
delegate<T>* bind(std::function<T> func)
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

So that I can now call

```
bind([&](int a) { // do something });
```

... So normally, this wouldn't be a problem, since std::function is able to capture a lambda. But here the problem is that (let's assume) I don't know or don't want to provide the info about what "T" is exactly. It could be any function signature you could also insert into std::function<>...

I also need to pass this "inferred" signature back to the "delegate" class I want to return and that delegate class needs to be a pointer to class...

For now I have come up with this:

```
template<class T>
struct delegate : public std::function<T>
{
    delegate(const std::function<T>& func) : std::function<T>(func) { }
    delegate(const delegate<T>& func) { }
};

template<class T>
delegate<T>* bind(std::function<T>&& func)
{
    return new delegate<T>(std::forward<std::function<T>>(func));
}
```

But the above example of a call to "bind" fails with "failed template argument deduction". How can I get this to work without having to specify the "T" parameter explicitly when calling "bind" (then it works, at least)?

Since in theory my compiler has all the info to workaround this issue, I could just insert the instance of "T", but this would make the generated code unnecessarily convoluted.

BTW, I am using the lastest Clang compiler.

---

Here is the final solution:

```
    template<typename T> struct get_signature;
template<typename Mem, typename Ret, typename... Args> struct get_signature<Ret(Mem::*)(Args...) const> {
    typedef Ret type(Args...);
};

template<class T> 
delegate<typename get_signature<decltype(&T::operator())>::type>* bind(T func)
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

Be aware that you may need to adjust the "const" modifiers to your needs.

Comment: It's not a wise idea to inherit from `std::function`. I'll bet you it doesn't have a virtual destructor.

Comment: There was something wrong with passing `std::function` as a parameter, but I don't remember what exactly.

Comment: Let's not worry about these details right now, I just want this template argument deduction to work! This is just a snippet demonstrating the idea. Might be that I mixed it up right now. I mean c++11 was meant to screw that passing by reference but I can remember that some things like shared_ptr and probably also std::function were an exception.

Comment: Your forwarding doesn't work as you expect it to because `std::function<T>&&` is not of the form `T&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have completely screwed up your rvalue references. Your forwarding does not work at all.

Secondly, that's impossible in some cases.. For *some function objects*, you could infer the signature by taking the member function pointer to `operator()` and inspecting it's signature. But for others, they will be overloaded and it will not work.

```
template<typename T> struct get_signature;
template<typename Mem, typename Ret, typename... Args> 
struct get_signature<Ret(Mem::*)(Args...)> {
    typedef Ret(Args...) type;
};

template<class T> 
delegate<typename get_signature<&T::operator()>::type>* bind(T func)
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

Thirdly, `std::bind`?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the rvalue thing... Because the way I have done it above is what I have read in tutorials ^^. So It would be nice to know whats wrong abotu it... I will try your code right now.

Comment: You won't see any tutorial do it that way. T *must be the type of the object*- not `std::function<T>`. `std::function<T>&&` is *always* an rvalue reference. And `std::forward` *must* take `T`- as it is, you have always forwarded it as an rvalue.

Comment: @thesaint For perfect forwarding, the type being deduced must be of the form `T&&`. Otherwise it's just a plain old rvalue reference, rather than a funky "universal reference".

Comment: well actually I have never seen "std::forward<std::function>()" in a tutorial ^^. But I am using "std::forward<TArgs>(args)..." for variadic forwadring so I thought it would extend like that to my above example. Probably a bit naive ;)

Comment: Clang does not compile your code :(. It has trouble with "typedef Ret(Args...) type;". The error message is almost 1000 characters too long for a comment ;). Could you look into it? Since I think this may solve the issue. I am only dealing with "normal" functions, so I guess they will not overload their operator.

Comment: Regarding the error message: you actually need either `typedef Ret type(Args...);` or `using type = Ret(Args...);` instead of that line.

Comment: Thanks, now it says "template argument for template type parameter must be a type" for the "&T::operator()" thing. Yeah I thought I knew something about C++ but when I see such things it feels as if I know nothing... Totally lost. I can only guess what this code does or would do when it compiled.

Comment: This is sick, but I found the solution thanks to you guys ;). Posted it above. Definitely something I will remember forever, because you can scare off anyone with it :D. Let's see what other compiler than Clang is able to compile it.